# How to handle Google Play version increment and IAB testing

Tags: air, in-app-purchase, google-play, version, in-app-billing

Our product version follows Semantic Versioning with an extra digit for build package identification:

`major.minor.patch.build`

The first 3 parts are for *source code versioning*, depending on API compatibility and bug fixes (patches). The last part is to keep track of multiple *build* packages. Multiple builds can happen with no source code changes (therefore no changes to `major.minor.patch`). Reasons for multiple builds are numerous all relating specifically to Android APK packaging (such Icons missing/changed, `minSDKVersion` increases, permission changes, SDK updates, descriptor-file changes [we are using AIR], etc)

Unfortunately, Google Play does not recognize this 4-part version. It only recognizes the first 3 parts. Example:

`2.3.1.1` - Uploaded, received warning about SDK/API min version mismatch.
`2.3.1.2` - No source code changes, only bumped `minSDKVersion` in manifest.
As far as Google Play is concerned, both are version `2.3.1` (`2003001`)

**Why does it matter?**
In order to test In-App-Billing (IAB) purchases, a version has to be published to Alpha (or Beta or Production). Once published, you cannot upload another APK without incrementing the version. As far as we are concerned, we **are** incrementing the version, but Google doesn't recognize that. For us, to bump the `patch` number when there were no source code changes is stupid and goes against the company versioning scheme which spans many more platforms then just Google Play.

**So what to do for IAB testing?**
- We distribute APKs to QA internally (not through Google Play), however we are still required to publish an APK to Alpha in order to test IAB.
- Without publishing an APK with increased version number, IAB testing errors out (APK version on device cannot be higher than the latest uploaded APK in Google Play)

How do others handle this?